# Telling Google to index a new page, without using Webmaster Tools

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site that generates a single page site for users from some fields they enter into a form and some images they upload. I want to get Google to come out and index the page but my users will not be technical enough to set their page up with Webmaster Tools. What can I do from WordPress when I build the page to tell Google a new page is up and to please come out and index it when they have a chance?

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't have to do anything actually, you could just sit back and wait for it to happen naturally. However there are things you could do to speed up the indexing process.

Here's a suggested way that does not involve having your users do anything: 
Create one or more (quality) links pointing to their single page site from other websites that you know are already indexed in Google (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LsB19wTt0Q for more information). Ideally on  blogs that get updated frequently because then then it is likely google crawls them more frequently.

Use a site:domain.com search in Google to see whether google has already found your new pages.

Here is how google crawling and indexing works:

> **Crawling:** 
>   Crawling is the process by which Googlebot discovers new and
>   updated pages to be added to the Google index.
>
> We use a huge set of computers to fetch (or "crawl") billions of pages
>   on the web. The program that does the fetching is called Googlebot
>   (also known as a robot, bot, or spider). Googlebot uses an algorithmic
>   process: computer programs determine which sites to crawl, how often,
>   and how many pages to fetch from each site.
>
> Google's crawl process begins with a list of web page URLs, generated
>   from previous crawl processes, and augmented with Sitemap data
>   provided by webmasters. As Googlebot visits each of these websites it
>   detects links on each page and adds them to its list of pages to
>   crawl. New sites, changes to existing sites, and dead links are noted
>   and used to update the Google index.
>
> Google doesn't accept payment to crawl a site more frequently, and we
>   keep the search side of our business separate from our
>   revenue-generating AdWords service.
>
> **Indexing:** 
>   Googlebot processes each of the pages it crawls in order to
>   compile a massive index of all the words it sees and their location on
>   each page. In addition, we process information included in key content
>   tags and attributes, such as Title tags and ALT attributes. Googlebot
>   can process many, but not all, content types. For example, we cannot
>   process the content of some rich media files or dynamic pages

Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/70897?hl=en